# Is this a parody of a real manga series in Sakurasou?

Tags: the-pet-girl-of-sakurasou

I saw this cover in episode 16 of Sakurasou no Pet na Kanojo.

[image: manga cover]

Is this a parody of some actual manga?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an actual manga called [*Hanaori Soushi*](http://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=62329), by Choujin.

[image: Hanaori Soushi]

> Having lost their parents at a young age, Chiharu and her brother find strength in each other. The past behind, the two live their lives in peace. However, the appearance of a new transfer student named Hisaya will put an end to these tranquil days. What does he want, and why does it involve Chiharu?